# How to set keyboard model and layout permanently?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 22.04, keyboard-layout

I bought a new keyboard in en english layout and I'd like to set the model to abnt2. I found a command to set the layout to use portuguese letters `çÇ`:

```
setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout us -variant intl
```

The problem is every time I restart my computer I need to run this command. How can I let it permanently?

PS: I've also tried this command but it didn't work on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

**Error: No such schema “org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard”**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```